# Documents are already indexed , detect duplicate documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Im firing the following query in elasticsearch

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "website",
      "query": "google OR yahoo"
    }
  }
}
```

Basically in the above query, the field of operation is "website" and I am looking for the keywords "google" or "yahoo" in that field. Now after firing this query a lot of results appear. But I need which of the given terms matched.

Comment: Your question is conflicting. Do you want to detected duplicate documents are find what term matched per answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) for this purpose

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "website",
      "query": "google OR yahoo"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "website": {
        "fragment_size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In response, for each document you will get something like this

```
"highlight": {
    "website": [
        "<em>google</em>"
    ]
}
```

and from that you can figure out which `term` matched.